# How do I move page one of a pdf to the last page?

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro 9 at work to edit a large number of scanned pdf documents. These are not OCRed. The information I need to quickly mail these documents out are on the first page, but my boss would like this page at the back. I can move the first page to the back using thumbnails, but this gets tedious with a large number of pdfs that are 20+ pages. So far, I am trying to modify a script I found from Bremen_Matt's post:

```
for (i = 0; i <= this.numPages/2-1; i++)
    this.movePage(this.numPages-1,this.numPages/2-i-1);
```

[How to write javascript to reorder pages of a pdf document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313267/how-to-write-javascript-to-reorder-pages-of-a-pdf-document)

I can almost get it to work, but when I try:

```
for(i=0;i<=this.numPages/2-2;)
    this.movePage(this.numPages-1);
```

or

```
for(i=0;i<=this.numPages;i)
     this.movePage(this.numPages-1);
```

I wind up crashing the program. Do you have any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: In the last two "for" loops you are not incrementing the "i" variabile. You should add "i++" as third element in the "for" construct

Comment: Activate the Debugger in the JavaScript tab of the Preferences, and you will see error messages, which help you fix the code.

Comment: @dbb I added the i++ operator in the third "for" parameter, which did allow the code to run. Unfortunately, the code did not seem to have any effect on the document: the first page remained on the first page. I wonder if there is something going on with the this.MovePage() arguments that need to be tweaked.

Comment: @Max Wyss I did enable the debugger in Acrobat, but the feedback can be hard to understand. I'm doing more research on "for" loops at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp. Finding the arguments for the this.MovePages statement is trickier because of a lack of documentation.

Comment: @JackOConner: The Acrobat JavaScript documentation is terse, but adequate (IMHO). The Acrobat JavaScript documentation is part of the Acrobat SDK documentation, downloadable from developer's section of the Adobe website.